# Port forwarding using IPTABLES to vpn client

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, port-forwarding, iptables

I  have been struggling for almost half a year now and I read almost all of the internet's solutions but none have worked.

The current solution which is also came from different articles is this:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 2254 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.8.2:22`

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 10.8.8.2 --dport 22 -j SNAT --to-source publicIP`

where `10.8.8.2` is my vpns client which I can ping and ssh from my iptables vps.

I wanted to forward port 2254 to my vpns client(home pc) from the outside world using my publicIP on port 2254 to vpns ip (10.8.8.2) with ssh port 22.

for example:

`ssh user@publicIP -p 2254`

`net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` was already enabled btw.

Comment: The --to-source IP needs to be the vpn-ip of your VPS - 10.8.8.1 perhaps?
Otherwise it sends a packet through the tunnel und receives the answer over public net from a different ip and thus ignores it.

Comment: It works!! How to mark that as answer?

Comment: I just reposted it as an answer ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The --to-source IP needs to be the vpn-ip of your VPS - 10.8.8.1 perhaps?

Otherwise it sends a packet through the tunnel and receives the answer over public net from a different IP and thus ignores it.

You can also use MASQUERADE instead of SNAT - this automatically uses the IP of the outgoing interface.